# Calculating the absorption length of attenuation?

Tags: nuclear-physics, absorption, attenuation

The flux of neutrons is attenuated according to the formula:

$$F = F_0 e^{-Ax}$$

And I want to find from the absorption length, defined as the length at which oncoming neutrons is reduced by a factor of $1/e$.

I set the exponential term equal to this and proceeded as follows:

$$e^{-Ax} = \frac{1}{e}$$

$$-Ax = \ln \frac{1}{e}$$

$$-Ax = -1$$

$$x = \frac{1}{A}$$

However, this gives me an absurdly large number. I'm not sure if there is a mistake in my algebra or whether the absorption length refers to something other than the flux.

Comment: As far as I know, $1/A$ definitely has units of length, i.e., $e^{-Ax}=e^{-\frac{x}{(1/A)}}$ and since the argument of the exponential should be dimensionless then $1/A$ should have units of length. More importantly, can you provide more context  about the problem at hand?

Comment: Since x has units of distance, A has units of reciprocal distance. That simple exponential decay expression is ubiquitous in science and engineering. For example, assume your F variables refer to incident and transmitted light intensity on an absorber. Then x is distance into the absorber and A is the absorption coefficient. In the Beer-Lambert law, A is a product of absorber concentration and absorber absorptivity.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. By definition when $x=\frac{1}{A}$ the neutron flux will decrease to a factor of $\frac{1}{e}$. As mentioned in comments above $Ax$ must also be dimensionless.

In the case of your example regarding neutron flux, as neutrons are not charged, as you have found, they can travel a significant distance through materials. This is one of the problems with D-T fusion as there is significant neutron production which must be shielded against.